# Can I use dt_txt instead of dt for date using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, date-formatting, openweathermap

I've been having problems rendering the dates even after formatting the dates.. I'm using openweather api for 3 hours forecast and trying to render the date as dt_txt format. Can I just use dt_txt for date instead of dt converting to simple date?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you retrieve the other data from the list it is hard to point you in the right direction. But I'll give it a try.

According to the docs `cnt` means that the list has 40 objects in your case.
You're only using the first one `[0]` over here:

```
date: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
              json['list'][0]['dt'] * 1000,
              isUtc: false)
```

If you want to use `dt_text` from each object you need to do something this using an index.

```
json['list'][index]['dt_txt']
```

A simple example using a for loop could also be:

```dart
List<String> dateList = [];
for(var data in json['list']){
  dateList.add(data['dt_txt']);
}
```

Comment: thank you I followed your solution and it worked. I'm now trying to iterate over each icon and get them rendered on the screen.. but getting an error "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' " .. how can I do it?